# Emulator AVD with white screen only after 27.0.2

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

Yesterday i have update the Emulator to 27.0.2 and today to 27.0.3

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html

But after 27.0.2 all Emulator with any version of Android and Device show always a white screen.

I'm really desperate I do not know how to do it.

## white screen avd

[image: white screen avd]

## update of today

[image: update of today]

Comment: Same issue, can you paste the error messages? Here is mine https://gist.github.com/vinz243/8444c82fb30e45f7372c8ec4c06da7a5

Comment: Same error for me =(

Comment: Google support say me to try this version:

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=12j3q2Xx6RgxPn4FuiyhWqDv9tShS2ags&export=download

and it work fine! Update with this fix is incoming =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with new version, on Windows and Mac =)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your **Emulated performance to automatic**

[image]
**Or**

Try uninstall and install Intel HAXM agin:

1. Go to the Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
2. Tap on SDK Tools and uncheck "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)"
3. After uninstall HAXM, install it again
4. Restart Android Studio

Comment: I can't try the first solution, the dropdown button is disabled, even when the device isn't running (after a reboot), and I don't get step 5 of your second proposal

Answer (score 1):

Try to "cold boot" emulator:

1. Go to "Your virtual devices"
2. Find the device
3. Click grey bottom pointing arrow on the right

   [image]
4. Click "Cold Boot Now"

   [image]